# Criar menu de fases que se auto atualiza, no Unity 5?

Tags: javascript, c#, menu, unity3d

Exemplo: No inicio do jogo o menu terá apenas o botão do Level 1, assim que o cara passar o level como criar um botão automático para o level 2 nesse menu? Botão este que o redirecionará para o level 2, assim que ele passar o level 2, irá aparecer um botão no menu com o Level3 e assim por diante.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Como usuário (mesmo que não tão antigo) digo-lhe sinceramente que suas perguntas tendem a ser como 0/0 - sem resposta bem determinada :P. Percebo que tendes a questionar sobre um projeto contínuo (um jogo, no caso). Se és novo no campo de Unity, recomendo que leia um tutorial na internet pois esse tipo de pergunta tende a não proceder no site. Sinceras desculpas.